# AWS S3 - Inserting into bucketed ORC table

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena, orc

I'm looking at storing data in `S3` in `ORC format` for querying with `Athena`.

I want to partition the data like so ...

```
.../year=2019/month=7/
```

... and bucketing the data further by id (each `id` will have multiple records for each month, there are lots of id's)

I want to be able to insert new data into this structure daily... I understand that I can't use the `INSERT INTO` statement from Athena because bucketed tables are not supported.

What would be the best way to insert data daily into a table of this structure? Is it even possible to do with bucketed data?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Presto allows inserts into existing partitions of bucketed partitioned tables since [Presto 312](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/release/release-312.html). If Athena does not support this, you can very easily run a Presto cluster yourself, e.g. using [Starburst Presto AWS integration](https://www.starburstdata.com/presto-aws-cloud/) (I can recommend this for other reasons too, as it can be way cheaper than using Athena if you run more than just few queries. Disclaimer: I'm from Starburst)

Comment: Thanks for your comment Piotr... I'm looking into this as an option, as cost is an important factor it may be the way to go